# Laravel - Get storage disk path

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a new storage disk for the public uploads. I use it like this:

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->get(...);
```

But I am trying to figure out a way to get the path to the disk itself, I have spent some considerable time wondering between the framework files, but couldn't find what I am looking for. I want to use it in a scenario like so:

```
$icon = $request->file('icon')->store('icons', 'uploads');
Image::make(Storage::disk('uploads')->path($icon))->resize(...)->save();
```

So, how to get a storage disk's path ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get path to file in storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969105/get-path-to-file-in-storage)

Answer (score 58):

**Update 2022**

You can get the path from the config:

```
config('filesystems.disks.uploads.root')
```

Anyway, I keep the old answer, as it still works and is not wrong:

---

There is a function for this!

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->path('');
```

https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_path

Looks like this has been there since 5.4! I never noticed...

Comment: For me, this appended "/" to make a double slash when my root was defined with storage_path("location"). It produced `path/to/location//`. With just an empty string '' as the parameter, it produced a path with a single slash. Is this anyone else's experience?

Comment: The link is outdated and doesn't work anymore. The following link works for Laravel 10.x: https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_path

Answer (score 35):

After extra search I found that I can use the following:

```
$path = Storage::disk('uploads')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
```

But still, isn't a "->path()" method is a given here or what!

Comment: I wondering where did you find the code?? there's not written in documentation, right?

Comment: I think it's from Flysystem package

Comment: No longer applicable in Laravel 9 however and for that I need a solution as well to replace `$this->storageDisk->getAdapter()->setPathPrefix(public_path('/uploads/'.$this->currentProject->id));`

Answer (score 7):

We can also access the disk storage path from configuration helper directly:

```
config('filesystems.disks');
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as the other ones require you to use functions that aren't on the interface.

Comment: Example [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57605029/1883256): `config('filesystems.disks.uploads.root')`

Answer (score 4):

There are helper functions in the framework now that can get some of the commonly used paths in the app fairly easily.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers

For example, if you wanted to access a file from the public folder you could do the below.

```php
    $image_file_path = public_path("images/my_image.jpg")
```

This will return you a local path for a file located in your app under the public/images folder.

Answer (score 4):

**Laravel Default Method**

```
return Storage::disk('disk_name')->path('');
```

**Get List of All Directories using disk name**

```
Storage::disk('disk_name')->directories()
```

Comment: Please expand your answer and explain why this works

Comment: Doesn't work, `path` needs a file name.

Comment: This code returned only the Disk default path that is defined in the config/filesystems.php

Comment: Is there a way to return the list (array) of files in that directory?

Comment: Get ALL Directory list from disk                                              
               Storage::disk('disk_name')->directories()