# Get path to file in storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I saved a file to storage using:

```
$request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

Which saved it to:

```
storage/app/avatars/avatar.png
```

How can I get the path to this file/folder (*not* the URL)? What is the correct way to do this using [Laravel's Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem)?

Comment: There is no correct way like @sisve said. I prefer to use `Storage::disk('public')->get(IMAGE_PATH);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correct way to do this; because it should not be done. The Storage is an opaque system to talk to different storage systems; as such there is no api to get the backing file path. As an example, that wouldn't work with Amazon S3. The only path your application knows about is the string you send to the Storage facade to work with the file, there are no guarantees that this string is used to generate the filename when the storage system stores the file.

There are some hacks you can use that works for the local disk, but those are not available for the Storage system in general. Using these solutions means that you'll limit yourself to only use the local disk; this will cause you troubles when you need to scale out and add another server. You'll then have two servers with two separate local disks, with separate content.

The correct way to work with the files, that will work for all configurations, is to get the file content (`Storage::get`), do the modifications (including storing them in a temporary file) and then write back the new file content (`Storage::set`).

If you're really sure that you will only ever use the local filesystem, use the [File facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html) instead of the Storage facade. I'm unable to find any documentation for this, only the interface it exposes.

Reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13610

Comment: Well, what about the `Storage::move()` ? I need the two relatives paths as arguments. How do I get those?

Comment: @Mirko I don't understand the question. You already know the $from, you passed it in when calling Storage::put(). You can pick the $to to match your need. `Storage::move('old-path/opaque-filename-1.txt', 'new-path/filename-2.txt')`.

Comment: I never call Storage::put(). I need to move files from one folder ("keep") to another ("bin"), files are already on the server. If I use Storage::move(), I cannot use absolute paths, and I found difficult to get the disk relative folder. Is it actually exposed by the Storage facade? I ended up writing the relative paths to a config file and call it on `filesystem.php` where my disks are declared and in the class where I use Storage::move();

Comment: @Mirko It sounds like you're using the local file system and should be using the File facade (with absolute paths) instead of the Storage facade.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

storage_path('app/avatars/avatar.png');

Answer (score 2):

you can only get the storage folder path from laravel function, you can give nested folder name after it, it will bind the base url as well

```
storage_path(folder1/folder2/.../file.png);
```